# winapi: self-suspending threads or creating new

Tags: c++, multithreading, winapi, suspend

I am developing a windows application that executes cyclically (once per second) two task without blocking the GUI. I implemented a Timer that at each WM_TIMER execution creates two new threads, the threads executed and returned after finished.

Reading some documentation I found references to the fact that threads can be suspended and resumed. For this reason I am wondering if a better approach can be to have only two thread: inside each thread a cycle can perform several time the requested task, but from one cycle to the other the thread suspends itself. The Timer can be used to resume the thread work each time. An event can signal the thread when to terminate.

Which is the most reliable and correct approach?

Thank you!

Comment: Just to clarify, the second approach allows not to continuosly create and destroy threads, but works only with two fixed threads.

Comment: Thread creation and destruction is expensive. So, on the face of it I'd err on the side of retaining the threads and having them block until needed.

Comment: Suspend/ResumeThread() are functions for a debugger, *never* use it in your own code.  You "suspend" a thread with WaitForSingleObject().  You probably should be using CreateTimerQueueTimer() here, its callback automatically runs on a threadpool thread.

Comment: Thank you, TimerQueue seems to be the correct solution to my problem!